# Querystring being ignored

Tags: c#, get, httpwebrequest, query-string

I'm writing an interface to scrape info from a service.  The link is behind a login, so I keep a copy of the cookies and then attempt to loop through the pages to get stats for our users.

The urls to hit are of the format: https://domain.com/groups/members/1234
for the first page, and each subsequent page appends ?page=X

```
string vUrl = "https://domain.com/groups/members/1234";
if (pageNumber > 1) vUrl += "?page=" + (pageNumber).ToString();
HttpWebRequest groupsRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(vUrl);
groupsRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
groupsRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); //recover cookies First request
groupsRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
groupsRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36";
groupsRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
groupsRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
groupsRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
groupsRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
groupsRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");

HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)groupsRequest.GetResponse();
```

This works fine for the first page and I get the data back that I need, but with each subsequent pass, the queryString is ignored.  Debugging at the last line shows that RequestUri.Query for the request is correct, but the response RequestUri.Query is blank.  So it has the effect of always returning page 1 data.

I've tried to mimic the request headers that I see via Inspect in Chrome, but I'm stuck.  Help?

Comment: How do you increment pageNumber ?

Comment: It's being passed into the method as an int, so incrementing is handled by the calling routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you put that url that is failing into a browser does it work?  Because it is a GET, the browser should make the same request and tell you if it is working.  If it does not work in the browser, then perhaps you are missing something aside from the query string?
If it does work, then maybe use fiddler and find out exactly what headers, cookies, and query string values are being sent to make 100% sure that you are sending the correct request.  It could be that the query string is not enough information to get the data that you need from the request that you are sending.

If you still can't get it then fiddler the request when you send it through the browser and then use [this fiddler extension](http://www.chadsowald.com/software/fiddler-extension-request-to-code) to turn the request into code and see whats up.

Comment: Yep, it works in the browser.  I haven't dug into Fiddler - I'll see if I can pull something from there.

Comment: Good call.  I edited my response to include something else you can try if all else fails.  There is a fiddler plugin you can use to turn that request into actual code.

Comment: Well - that did it!  There's nothing obvious other than it's ignoring the cookies that I captured and explicitly creating them again.  Thanks for the tip on that code creator too - really makes it easy.

If anyone else come across this, I just dragged my Fiddler session over to the code tab, then copied all the HttpWebRequest generation code over to my app.  

Thanks Jerrod!

Comment: You're welcome.  Yeah man.  I can't tell you how many days I have burned on similar issues.